# How to "push" the whole page content to left?

Tags: html, css

I try to achieve the side navbar just looks like this website:
https://shop.hitsujigusa.com/

And I'm using the W3Schools method now (the push one):
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sidenav.asp

But the W3Schools method is much more looks like "squish" the page not "push".
And I also want to open and close the menu using the same button, not separate.

how can I do this? much appreciate!

this is my html now:

```
 <body>  
        <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">
              X
            </a>
            <a href="#">home</a>
            <a href="#">about</a>
            <a href="#">products</a>
            <a href="#">contact</a>
            <a href="#">links</a>
        </div>
        
        <div id="main">
           (...content here...)
        </div>
```

and the js

```
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginRight = "250px";
  }
  
function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginRight= "0";
  }
```

Comment: Everything is well explained on the site (W3Schools ) you copied the content. Just take your time and go through it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need the w3schools example and the one below, here is why.  On mobile you will not have the space to squish the content and make it look good but on desktop you will and you don't want to move your content out of its container. So on mobile set the width and transform translate dynamically through JavaScript and when you get to desktop squish your content using width and margin as they do in the w3schools example.

```js
const menuButton = document.getElementById("toggle-menu");
const mainNav = document.getElementById("main-nav");
const mainList = document.getElementById("main-list");
const mainContent = document.getElementById("main-content");

const toggleMenu = () => {
  const listWidth = mainList.offsetWidth;
  if (mainNav.getAttribute("aria-hidden") === "true") {
    mainNav.style.width = listWidth + "px";
    mainNav.setAttribute("aria-hidden", "false")
    mainContent.style.transform = "translate(-" + listWidth + "px)"
  } else {
    mainNav.style.width = "0px";
    mainNav.setAttribute("aria-hidden", "true");
    mainContent.style.transform = "translateX(0)"
  }
}

menuButton.addEventListener("click", toggleMenu);
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  /* for the example */
  border: 3px solid red;
  width: 375px;
  height: 667px;
  margin-left: 87px;
}

.navigation {
  width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  transition: width .3s ease-in-out;
}

#main-list {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  width: min-content;
}

#main-content {
  transition: transform .3s ease-in-out;
  /* for the example */
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header><button id="toggle-menu">toggle menu</button></header>
<div class="container">
  <div id="main-content">
    (...content here...)</main>
  </div>
  <nav id="main-nav" class="navigation" aria-hidden="true">
    <ul id="main-list">
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">
              X
            </a></li>
      <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">products</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">links</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! but one thing that confused me is when I put the js code into... let's says "sidenav.js" file, and use "<script src="js/sidenav.js">, the function won't work, it only works when I put the js code into index.html file

Comment: If it works in the html file it should work in an external JavaScript file.  Ensure that your src file path is correct and place the call to your `<script src="js/sidenav.js"` just before the closing body tag.